# Show that $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x) =\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x \lambda)$ We imply that if one limit exists then so does the other.

Tags: limits, functions

Show that $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x) =\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x \lambda)$ We imply that if one limit exists then so does the other.

Comment: Yes, because when $x\to 0$, $u\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{ax}{2} \to 0$ as well. What is the part that confuses you there, *exactly*?

Comment: Do you know the limit
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1? $$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Clement C. I am using mobile app. It is showing only some messed code. As for confusion part, I was confirming as well as wanted to know on how to better simplify this in exams. Sorry , if u find it silly but for me the marks decide my future and i have to know how can i maximize them.

Comment: @DiagaAoS I never said it was silly. I was asking which part you were confused about: that $\frac{\sin u(t)}{u(t)} \to 1$ when $t\to 0$ (assuming $u(t)\to 0$), or the part saying that $u(t)\to 0$ when $t\to 0$.

Comment: @Clement C.  "Exactly" written in italics alongwith the downvote. But i apologize if i misunderstood. And as i said before, i can only see some code in comments , so can't understand it.

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions. (1) I was trying to help, and took the time to type a comment that I deem relevant, even though it does not display on your phone. (2) Why the hell do you assume I downvoted?

Comment: @Clement C. I suppose i should thankyou for your time. And i assumed that because you wrote "exactly" in italics or did you have another reason to do so? Also , if u help someone u do it willingly.

Comment: @DiagaAoS I too see markup code instead of formatted math in comments when I use the mobile app, but if I tap three times (once on the comment, once on the "more" symbol, once on "Render MathJax") it will show the comment properly formatted. Sometimes I find this useful to do. (Most of the time I can "see" the formatting in my mind because I have used LaTeX for so long.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \to 0$ then $ax \to 0$ for any constant $a$. Now try a substitution of variables $y=ax/2$.

Comment: More to the point is that $ax/2\to0.$ That means $y\to0. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Of course if $x$ approaches $0$, $ax$ as well. Because $0=a0$.

Actually, anything that goes to zero can do. For instance,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\arcsin x}{\arcsin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\arcsin x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\frac{ax}{2})}{\frac{ax}{2}}$$
can be found using LHT
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\frac{ax}{2})}{\frac{ax}{2}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{a}{2}\cos (\frac{ax}{2})}{\frac{a}{2}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \cos (\frac{ax}{2}) = 1$$